# Read symbols from from the text file?

Tags: char, pascal

```
10
Balta          B 1 15
Melyna         M 2 15
Zalia          Z 3 12
Raduona        R 4 10
Geltona        G 5 10
Violetine      V 6 12
Pilka          P 7 10
Oranzine       O 8 12
Alyvuogiu      A 9 12
Juoda          J 10 10
3 5
Andrius        B 4 P 7 R 4 B 1 V 6
Tomas          V 6 A 9 B 6 O 8 P 2
Evelina        R 4 P 7 R 4 P 7 B 1


program Spalvotos_korteles;
 type Spalvos = record
       SPav : string[15];            // SpalvosPavadinimas
       SNr, SSk : integer;          //  SpalvosNumeris, SpalvosSkaicius
       SI : char;                  //   SpalvuIndeksas
      end;
      Mokiniai = record
       V : string[15];             // Mokinio vardas
       MI : char;                 //  Mokinio istrauktas indeksas
       Mnr, TR, NR : integer;            //   Mokinio uzrasytas numeris   TeisingiRasymai, NeteisingiRasymai
      end;
 Mas  = array[1..100] of Spalvos;
 Mas1 = array[1..100] of Mokiniai;
 Mas2 = array[1..100] of char;
 Mas3 = array[1..100] of integer;

  var n, Q, MokSk, MokT  : integer;
      S : Mas;
      M : Mas1;
      VI : Mas2;          // Visi Indeksai
      VNr, Istraukta, TeisingiRasymai, Nepanaudota : Mas3;         // VNr - Visi Numeriai

 procedure Nuskaitymas;
  var df : text;
      Qq, i, j, z, ii : integer;
  begin
   Qq:=1;
   assign(df,'duom.txt');
   reset(df);
   readln(df, n);
    for i:= 1 to n do
     readln(df, S[i].SPav, S[i].SI, S[i].SNr, S[i].SSk);

     readln(df, MokSk, MokT);
     for j := 1 to MokSk do
      begin
       read(df,M[j].V);
        for z := 1 to MokT do
         begin
          read(df, M[z].MI, M[z].Mnr);
             VI[Qq] := M[z].MI;
             VNr[Qq] := M[z].Mnr;
           Qq:=Qq+1;
            for ii := 1 to n do
             if (M[z].MI = S[ii].SI) and (M[z].Mnr = S[ii].SNr) then  M[j].TR := M[j].TR+1;


           end;
          end;

         Q:=Qq-1;
         close(df);
      end;

  procedure Uzrasymai_ant_korteliu;
   var i, j : integer;
    begin
       for i:= 1 to n do
        begin
         for j:= 1 to Q do
          begin
           if S[i].SI = VI[j] then
            Istraukta[i]:=Istraukta[i]+1;
           if (S[i].SI = VI[j]) and (S[i].SNr = VNr[j]) then
            TeisingiRasymai[i]:= TeisingiRasymai[i]+1;
          end;
           Nepanaudota[i]:= S[i].SSk - Istraukta[i];
          end;
    end;

  procedure Rezultatas;
   var i, j : integer;
       Rf : text;
    begin
     assign(rf,'SpalvuRezultas.Txt');
     rewrite(rf);
      for i := 1 to MokSk do
       writeln(rf,M[i].V, M[i].TR);
       writeln(rf);
      for j := 1 to n do
       writeln(rf,S[j].SPav, Istraukta[j], TeisingiRasymai[j], Nepanaudota[j]);
      close(rf);
    end;
   begin
    Nuskaitymas;
    Uzrasymai_ant_korteliu;
    Rezultatas;
   end.
```

My goal is to read the 3 last roads and look how many  numbers by the symbols are correct (the correct ones are symbol & first number from the columns) but when I try to read then I get the 106error wrong numeric format. I somehow understand that the problem because of the char symbols but I have no clue how to fix it. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to find out how the program interprets your `read` statement in your program.

Let ch, ch1, ch2 ... be a char and int, int1, int2 ... be an integer.

```
INPUT:

P 1 C 2
```

execute `read(ch, int)`

```
RESULT:

ch = P
int = 1
```

It works perfectly ok.

Let's expand this to read four elements.

```
INPUT:

P 1 C 2
```

execute `read(ch1, int1, ch2, int2)`

```
RESULT:

ch1 = P
int1 = 1
ch2 = C
int2 = 2
```

However,

```
INPUT:

P 1 C 2
```

execute `read(ch1, int1); read(ch2, int2);`

```
RESULT:

ch1 = P
int1 = 1
ERROR 106 when execute read(ch2, int2);
```

Why?

Let's see the following illustration.

```
reading ch1

1234567
P 1 C 2
^
```

The first read(ch1, int1) asks the program to read a char and then a integer, separated by SPACE. The program first read a char and move the pointer to position 2 and then knows it is a SPACE so move on read the next int which move the pointer to position 3.

```
reading int1

1234567
P 1 C 2
  ^
```

So it reads 1 into int1. And move the pointer to the next position. Then the first `read` is finished.

```
1234567
P 1 C 2
   ^
```

What's going on? Second `read` will read the char on position 4 which is a SPACE. It won't give out any warning as it is really a character. After that the position of pointer should be on position 5.

```
1234567
P 1 C 2
    ^
```

The program will not skip position 5 as it is not a SPACE. Therefore, 'C' is read into int2. As 'C' is not an integer, the program gives out a RUNTIME ERROR 106.

It seems that `readln(df, S[i].SPav, S[i].SI, S[i].SNr, S[i].SSk);` and `read(df,M[j].V);read(df, M[z].MI, M[z].Mnr);` have the same logic, but in the execution, they do not.

Moreover, you have to go to the next line after you have read all elements on a row by `readln(df);`.

---

FYI, below is the edited code:

```
program post;

type
    Spalvos = record
        SPav: string[15];            // SpalvosPavadinimas
        SNr, SSk: integer;          //  SpalvosNumeris, SpalvosSkaicius
        SI: char;                  //   SpalvuIndeksas
    end;

    Mokiniai = record
        V: string[15];             // Mokinio vardas
        MI: char;                 //  Mokinio istrauktas indeksas
        Mnr, TR, NR: integer;
        //   Mokinio uzrasytas numeris   TeisingiRasymai, NeteisingiRasymai
    end;
    Mas = array[1..100] of Spalvos;
    Mas1 = array[1..100] of Mokiniai;
    Mas2 = array[1..100] of char;
    Mas3 = array[1..100] of integer;

var
    n, Q, MokSk, MokT: integer;
    S: Mas;
    M: Mas1;
    VI: Mas2;          // Visi Indeksai
    VNr, Istraukta, TeisingiRasymai, Nepanaudota: Mas3;         // VNr - Visi Numeriai
    temp: char;

    procedure Nuskaitymas;
    var
        df: Text;
        Qq, i, j, z, ii: integer;
    begin
        Qq := 1;
        Assign(df, 'duom.txt');
        reset(df);
        readln(df, n);
        for i := 1 to n do
            readln(df, S[i].SPav, S[i].SI, S[i].SNr, S[i].SSk);
        readln(df, MokSk, MokT);
        for j := 1 to MokSk do
        begin
            Read(df, M[j].V);
            for z := 1 to MokT do
            begin
                Read(df, M[z].MI, M[z].Mnr, temp);
                writeln(M[z].MI, M[z].Mnr);
                VI[Qq] := M[z].MI;
                VNr[Qq] := M[z].Mnr;
                Qq := Qq + 1;
                for ii := 1 to n do
                    if (M[z].MI = S[ii].SI) and (M[z].Mnr = S[ii].SNr) then
                        M[j].TR := M[j].TR + 1;
            end;
            readln(df);
        end;
        Q := Qq - 1;
        Close(df);
    end;

    procedure Uzrasymai_ant_korteliu;
    var
        i, j: integer;
    begin
        for i := 1 to n do
        begin
            for j := 1 to Q do
            begin
                if S[i].SI = VI[j] then
                    Istraukta[i] := Istraukta[i] + 1;
                if (S[i].SI = VI[j]) and (S[i].SNr = VNr[j]) then
                    TeisingiRasymai[i] := TeisingiRasymai[i] + 1;
            end;
            Nepanaudota[i] := S[i].SSk - Istraukta[i];
        end;
    end;

    procedure Rezultatas;
    var
        i, j: integer;
        Rf: Text;
    begin
        Assign(rf, 'SpalvuRezultas.Txt');
        rewrite(rf);
        for i := 1 to MokSk do
            writeln(rf, M[i].V, M[i].TR);
        writeln(rf);
        for j := 1 to n do
            writeln(rf, S[j].SPav, Istraukta[j], TeisingiRasymai[j], Nepanaudota[j]);
        Close(rf);
    end;

begin
    Nuskaitymas;
    Uzrasymai_ant_korteliu;
    Rezultatas;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, but I already found out about char reading spaces too and I fixed it. Don't know if it is the best way but it works.

```
 readln(df, MokSk, MokT);
 for j := 1 to MokSk do
  begin

   read(df,M[j].V);
      for z := 1 to MokT-1 do
     begin
      read(df, MI, Mnr, Tuscias);                //  M[z].MI P      M[z].Mnr O
       VI[Qq] := MI;
         VNr[Qq] := Mnr;
         Qq:=Qq+1;
          for ii := 1 to n do
         if (MI = S[ii].SI) and (Mnr = S[ii].SNr) then  M[j].TR := M[j].TR+1;
        end;
         read(df, MI, Mnr);
           VI[Qq] := MI;
           VNr[Qq] := Mnr;
           Qq:=Qq+1;
          for ii := 1 to n do
         if (MI = S[ii].SI) and (Mnr = S[ii].SNr) then  M[j].TR := M[j].TR+1;
          readln(df);
        end;

Andrius        B 4 P 7 R 4 B 1 V 6
Tomas          V 6 A 9 B 6 O 8 P 2
Evelina        R 4 P 7 R 4 P 7 B 1
```

I don't know any other way to read this program, so I made it like this.

P.s. I tried your way before but it didn't work because after the last pair there's no space and the program makes an error out of it. But thanks for your help kind sir :)